# how do i organize flash messages with validation errors within controller

Tags: flash, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, notice

Here is an example of model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_secure_password

validates :login, :presence => { :message => 'please, provide a password' }, :uniqueness => true
validates :password, :presence => true, :confirmation => true
...etc...
end
```

Here is what i've got in controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def create
@user = User.create(user_params)

if @user.save
 redirect_to(:action => 'login', :controller => 'access')
else
 redirect_to(:action => 'index', :controller => 'registration')
 flash[:notice] = @user.errors.full_messages   
 end
end
```

I have a render function under registration form:

```
<%= render 'layouts/error_messages' %>
```

And the partial view itself:

```
<%# Rails flash messages styled for Bootstrap 3.0 %>
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
   <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
     <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "danger" %>">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;  </button>
       <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
     </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It does not work,  so i need a hand. Thank you.

Comment: Forgot to add that i am using rails 4.0.2, ruby 2

Comment: solve the issue by typing this flash[:notice] = "#{user.errors.full_messages}"

instead of this

    flash[:notice] = @user.errors.full_messages   

to have an access to the object errors

Answer (score 0):

I think that it fails because **msg** is not a string, but array of strings, so it won't show up.

I've created a handy module which I include in my application controller (flash.rb):

https://gist.github.com/Rabsztok/9018332

this allows me to create flash messages in controller using simple methods like

```
if @user.save
  Emailer.email_confirmation(@user).deliver
  success 'Registered!'
else
  error_for @user
end
```

I've included also my partial for displaying flash (render it wherever you like in your layout) and helper with a metod creating handy error list which could be placed above form with validation. It will create red error message with a list of errors.